# db:migrate not working when trying to seed a heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am running into a really frustrating issue trying to deploy a project where I cannot run either heroku run rails db:migrate or heroku run rails db:seed. Whenever I run the migration I get

```
I, [2022-03-10T21:19:22.493216 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to ChangeWatchListToWatchlist (20211215190119)
== 20211215190119 ChangeWatchListToWatchlist: migrating =======================
-- rename_table(:watch_list, :list)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "watch_list" does not exist
```

I think I see the problem not sure if it is a big deal but when I renamed watch_list to list it looks like the migration was titled ChangeWatchListToWatchlist all of the logic in migration works locally so I'm not sure if that is even it if it is that I don't know how to fix it even after a ton of time searching because my app worked up to this point and when I run heroku run rails db:seed I get

```
You have 15 pending migrations:
  20211119213309 CreateUsers
  20211119213507 CreateWatchLists
  20211119213606 CreateMovies
  20211203193100 AddYearToMovies
  20211214214115 AddCategoryToWatchLists
  20211215190119 ChangeWatchListToWatchlist
  20211215191400 ChangeListToLists
  20220108201512 AddCategoryToMovies
  20220108201837 AddWatchedToMovies
  20220110195706 CreateLovedits
  20220111154531 AddUserIdToLovedits
  20220111233324 AddBoxArtToLovedIts
  20220112214244 CreateHatedits
  20220122200328 RemoveCategoryFromLists
  20220122200621 RemoveWatchedFromMovies
Run `bin/rails db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

I have tried to force it to run through and I am getting absolutely nowhere being really new to all of this and with this being the first app I have ever tried to deploy the frustration is getting high so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Protip: If you have 15 pending migrations on production you're most likely doing something very wrong. You should implement your feature; run the migrations locally and in production and then delete them as they are just programatical transformations to the DB schema and shouldn't hang around for the entire life of your app.

Comment: Ok so if I delete them it should cooperate because I had it working locally and I've tried migrating locally and it works but when I try to dump my seeds file in production it gives me that error